# The postinstall intercept hook 'update_gio_module_cache' failed

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, intel, yocto

I am building `core-image-minimal` for warrior branch. My device has **atom** processor so I have changed `nehalem` to `atom` in `tune-corei7.inc` file. My machine is set to **intel-corei7-64**. While generating `core-image-minimal`, I am facing following error:

```
NOTE: Installing complementary packages ... 
NOTE: Running ['oe-pkgdata-util', '-p', '/home/panther2/warrior/build_panther1/tmp/pkgdata/panther1', 'glob', '/tmp/installed-pkgs03hhi936', ''] 
NOTE: Running intercept scripts:
NOTE: > Executing update_gio_module_cache intercept ... 
NOTE: Exit code 1. Output:
+ [ True = False -a qemuwrapper-cross != nativesdk-qemuwrapper-cross ]
+ qemu-x86_64 -r 3.2.0 -cpu atom,check=false -E LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/panther2/warrior/build_panther1/tmp/work/panther1-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/lib:/home/panther2/warrior/build_panther1/tmp/work/panther1-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/rootfs/lib -L /home/panther2/warrior/build_panther1/tmp/work/panther1-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/rootfs /home/panther2/warrior/build_panther1/tmp/work/panther1-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/libexec/gio-querymodules /home/panther2/warrior/build_panther1/tmp/work/panther1-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/lib/gio/modules/
unable to find CPU model 'atom'

ERROR: The postinstall intercept hook 'update_gio_module_cache' failed, details in /home/panther2/warrior/build_panther1/tmp/work/panther1-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs
ERROR: 
DEBUG: Python function do_rootfs finished
ERROR: Function failed: do_rootfs
```

> Any help here?

Thanks in advance..!

**Edit : Attaching "tune-corei7.inc" file**

```
# Settings for the GCC(1) cpu-type "atom":
#
#     Intel atom CPU with 64-bit extensions, MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1,
#     SSE4.2 and POPCNT instruction set support.
#
# This tune is recommended for Intel atom and Silvermont (e.g. Bay Trail) CPUs
# (and beyond).
#
DEFAULTTUNE ?= "corei7-64"

# Include the previous tune to pull in PACKAGE_EXTRA_ARCHS
require conf/machine/include/tune-atom.inc

# Extra tune features
TUNEVALID[corei7] = "Enable corei7 specific processor optimizations"
TUNE_CCARGS .= "${@bb.utils.contains('TUNE_FEATURES', 'corei7', ' -march=atom -mtune=generic -mfpmath=sse -msse4.2', '', d)}"

# Extra tune selections
AVAILTUNES += "corei7-32"
TUNE_FEATURES_tune-corei7-32 = "${TUNE_FEATURES_tune-x86} corei7"
BASE_LIB_tune-corei7-32 = "lib"
TUNE_PKGARCH_tune-corei7-32 = "corei7-32"
PACKAGE_EXTRA_ARCHS_tune-corei7-32 = "${PACKAGE_EXTRA_ARCHS_tune-atom-32} corei7-32"
QEMU_EXTRAOPTIONS_corei7-32 = " -cpu nehalem,check=false"

AVAILTUNES += "corei7-64"
TUNE_FEATURES_tune-corei7-64 = "${TUNE_FEATURES_tune-x86-64} corei7"
BASE_LIB_tune-corei7-64 = "lib64"
TUNE_PKGARCH_tune-corei7-64 = "corei7-64"
PACKAGE_EXTRA_ARCHS_tune-corei7-64 = "${PACKAGE_EXTRA_ARCHS_tune-atom-64} corei7-64"
QEMU_EXTRAOPTIONS_corei7-64 = " -cpu nehalem,check=false"

AVAILTUNES += "corei7-64-x32"
TUNE_FEATURES_tune-corei7-64-x32 = "${TUNE_FEATURES_tune-x86-64-x32} corei7"
BASE_LIB_tune-corei7-64-x32 = "libx32"
TUNE_PKGARCH_tune-corei7-64-x32 = "corei7-64-x32"
PACKAGE_EXTRA_ARCHS_tune-corei7-64-x32 = "${PACKAGE_EXTRA_ARCHS_tune-atom-64-x32} corei7-64-x32"
QEMU_EXTRAOPTIONS_corei7-64-x32 = " -cpu nehalem,check=false"
```

Comment: Oh, this part needs something that qemu recognizes.  You can presumably still use nehalem for qemu, even though you need to compile with `gcc -march=atom` for your code to run on Atom.  Since you're hacking up the build process anyway to repurpose corei7 as atom, you might as well change this too.

Comment: Thanks Peter! with above suggestion, I got same error with small change(`unable to find CPU model 'nehalem'`) Edit: I have attached `tune-corei7.inc` file in question

Comment: Obviously you should run qemu with `--help` or something and see what CPU models it supports.  Pick something that's a superset of Atom.  (If you even need an emulator; likely your desktop supports all the instructions that Atom does, including `movbe` (byte swap) if it's new enough; that instruction was introduced first on Atom but later supported on desktops.)